# I have JRE installed and I want to install JDK

Tags: java, java-8

I have a JRE already installed on my system, but looks that I need to install JDK.
Is it possible to keep the JRE installed and install JDK also or I should to remove the JRE before.

any advice? because it should be better for me if I don't delete any old programme.

Comment: [idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/). Please see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: remove jre and install jdk because jdk already has jre inside

Comment: You can install as many versions as you want, just change your path to point to the one you want

Comment: you can keep it and still install. nothing is stopping you to try

Answer (score 0):

You can install `JDK` without uninstalling `JRE`. It will be ok and work fine.

**BUT**

*You should note that `JDK` comes with `JRE`, so you no need to install it separately. Also, You can install different `JDK` versions (e.g. `jdk1.7.0_51`, `jdk1.8.0_149`, `jdk1.8.0_151`, `jdk1.7.0_58`) side by side and all will work fine.*